# multiple step gathering of columns in R

Tags: r, dataframe, multiple-columns, tidyr

I have data.frame like this:

```
df<-data.frame(Time=c(1:100),Rome_population=c(1:100),Rome_gdp=c(1:100),Rome_LifeLenght=c(1:100),London_population=c(1:100),London_gdp=c(1:100),London_LifeLenght=c(1:100),Berlin_population=c(1:100),Berlin_gdp=c(1:100),Berlin_LifeLenght=c(1:100))
```

And I would like to have a data.frame like this:
df<-data.frame(Time,City,population,gdp,LifeLenght)

How can I make it? Possibly with tidyr?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
df %>% 
  gather(key, value, Rome_population:Berlin_LifeLenght) %>% 
  separate(key, into = c("city", "stat"), sep = "_") %>% 
  spread(stat, value)
```

Output:

```
 # A tibble: 300 x 5
    Time city     gdp LifeLenght population
   <int> <chr>  <int>      <int>      <int>
 1     1 Berlin     1          1          1
 2     1 London     1          1          1
 3     1 Rome       1          1          1
 4     2 Berlin     2          2          2
 5     2 London     2          2          2
 6     2 Rome       2          2          2
 7     3 Berlin     3          3          3
 8     3 London     3          3          3
 9     3 Rome       3          3          3
10     4 Berlin     4          4          4
# ... with 290 more rows
```